# How do I paginate and sort sub-document array MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I'm trying to paginate, and sort(createdAt) sub-document array. But it's not working. I need to paginate this *transactionHistory* array.
perpage = 2;
How would anyone go around doing this the easiest / most affective way?

```
{
        "_id": "619623e27525bd59cd5dbaa4",
        "nidNumber": 123456789,
        "referralCode": "12345",
        "transactionHistory": [
            {
                "transactionId": {
                    "_id": "61a8749758a558600557f0fd",
                    "amount": 500,
                    "createdAt": "2021-12-02T07:24:07.653Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-12-02T07:24:07.653Z",
                },
                "_id": "61a8749758a558600557f100"
            },
            {
                "transactionId": {
                    "_id": "61a8755dc0c3aa99c5ae45d3",
                    "amount": 500,
                    "createdAt": "2021-12-02T07:27:25.384Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-12-02T07:27:25.384Z",
                },
                "_id": "61a8755dc0c3aa99c5ae45d6"
            },
            {
                "transactionId": {
                    "_id": "61a875e9be563a549fa209db",
                    "amount": 50,
                    "createdAt": "2021-12-02T07:29:45.042Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-12-02T07:29:45.042Z",
                },
                "_id": "61a875e9be563a549fa209de"
            },
            {
                "transactionId": {
                    "_id": "61a87e57dbe5bc661900244a",
                    "amount": 50,
                    "createdAt": "2021-12-02T08:05:43.018Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-12-02T08:05:43.018Z",
                },
                "_id": "61a87e57dbe5bc661900244d"
            },
            {
                "transactionId": {
                    "_id": "61a8863607ffafc2f598b032",
                    "amount": 50,
                    "createdAt": "2021-12-02T08:39:18.289Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-12-02T08:39:18.289Z",
                },
                "_id": "61a8863607ffafc2f598b035"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$unwind`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "619623e27525bd59cd5dbaa4"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$transactionHistory"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "transactionHistory.transactionId.createdAt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 2
  },
  {
    "$limit": 2
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_BevtatXnfi)

Comment: thank you for sorting this data. can you paginate this array?

Comment: @SakilKhan I update my answer